# $A$ is $n\times n$ complex matrix with $A^2=A$. then need to show that Rank$A$=Trace$A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So, I have that $A^n=A$ for every natural number $n$ which gives me that determinant of $A$ is either $0$ or the $(n-1)^{th}$ roots of unity, but I don't know how to take it from here.What do I do now? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already have $n=2$ and there aren't that many "$1$th" roots of unity: what's $\sqrt[1]{1}$?

Comment: What is your assumption? Do you have a single n by n matix A, for which all of its powers equal A? [Guess that's same as $A^2=A.$

Comment: Uh, so what i'm saying is that I deduce these two things from the hypothesis of the problem, but don't know how to proceed. Should I try taking the trace on both sides of the equation and see what happens?

Comment: @ErickWong it's just 1 but I don't get your point

Comment: Do you know what a "minimal polynomial" is?  Do you know anything about Jordan canonical form?

Comment: I do know about both, yes

Comment: @DeepishaSolanki You have that the eigenvalues of $A$ are 0 or $(n-1)$th roots of unity for *all* $n$.  There's only one number that's an $(n-1)$th root of unity for all $n$, namely $1$ (as could have been seen by just sticking with $n=2$).  So you already know the eigenvalues are $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @ErickWong Well, that's what I thought initially, that the condition would hold for all $n$ but took a rain check on that because the $n$ given to us, thought arbitrary, is fixed, isn't it?

Comment: @DeepishaSolanki That's merely because you abused notation and used $n$ to mean two different things.  It's still true that $A^k=A$ for all $k$.

Comment: @ErickWong umm alright I think I see it, since this equality holds for all $k$, so does the condition on eigenvalues?

Comment: @DeepishaSolanki Well, yes, by a simple calculation.  Didn't you already say you know that the eigenvalues are either $0$ or $(n-1)$th roots of unity??

Comment: @ErickWong, yeah makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ an eigen value of $A$ then $AX=\lambda X$ and so $A^2X=\lambda^2 X$ what give us:

$$A^2X=AX \Rightarrow \lambda^2X=\lambda X \Rightarrow \lambda^2-\lambda=0 \Rightarrow \lambda =0 \ or \ \lambda =1$$

That means we have $m$ eigenvalues equal to $0$ and $n$ eigenvalues equal to $1$.

But we know that

$trace(A)=$ sum of eigenvalues $=n$

Also, by Jordan Form,

$rank(A)=$ number of non-null eigenvalue $=n$.

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Comment: you are very welcome!

Comment: This assumes that $A$ is diagonalizable, which needs to be proven (not very hard, though).

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is a projection matrix. So, if Rank $A$ equals $m$ you have a set 
$\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_m\}$ of eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$. You can complete to a basis of $\mathbb C^n$, say 
$\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_m,u_{m+1},\dots,u_n\}$ such that $Au_j=0$ if $j>m$.

Therefore, $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix with $m$ ones and $n-m$ zeroes. Since the trace is invariant under matrix similarity you obtain the result.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your matrix is either $0$ or $I$, its minimal polynomial is $x^2 - x = (x-1) x$.  Therefore the characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^j x^{n-j}$ for some $j$, $0 \le j \le n$.  Show that the rank and trace are both $j$.

Comment: Umm, so I'd use Jordan form to do that right? So, I can see trace would be $j$ because similar matrices have the same trace and then rank also using Jordan form by the result mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in\Bbb R^n$ we have $x=(x-Ax)+Ax$ and since $x-Ax\in\ker A$ and $Ax\in Im (A)$ and by the rank-nullity theorem we have
$$\Bbb R^n=Im(A)\oplus \ker(A)$$
Let $p=rank(A)$ and let $\mathcal B=(e_1,\ldots,e_p)$ a basis of $Im(A)$ and $(e_{p+1},\ldots,e_n)$ a basis of $\ker A$ so $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^n$. It's easy to prove that $x\in Im(A)\iff Ax=x$ so we see that $A$ is similar to this matrix (relative to the basis $\mathcal B$)
$$D=diag(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{p\,\text{times}},0,\ldots,0)$$
hence
$$Tr(A)=Tr(D)=p=rank(A)$$

Comment: very detailed, thanks a lot!